# Issue with lightning:icon tag

Tags: lightning

I am trying to use to lightning:icon tag to display icon in lightning component. It shows only alternative text.

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" 
                              alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Have you used *extends="force:slds"* in your component?

Comment: I tried and looks like, this can be used on application not in component.

Comment: Are you running your component from inside an Application? There is nothing wrong with your component markup.

Comment: No, I need to use this on communities page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser developer console. If you see an error like below, this means the SVG icons are not loaded.

[image]

To resolve this you should use extends="force:slds" in aura application. Check this example below.

App Code

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:iconComponent />
</aura:application>
```

Component Code

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" 
                    alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
</aura:component>
```

> Change the background color of the Icon

To change the background color of the ICON you can add this below CSS class to the component CSS file.

```
.THIS.slds-icon-action-approval {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I need to use this component with icon in communities.

Comment: Generated icon is white in color, hence I need to add background color as below: `<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
    <div style="background:green;">
       <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
    </div>
  
</aura:component>`

Comment: Check my updated answer.